# Pandas how to create a new column by seleting correct values from origianl column?

Tags: python, pandas

How to create a new column(C) by dynamic select the value from column(B)?
For example as blow, if column B's value bigger than 3 than put than into new column(C)

Original DataFrame

```
  A B
0 a 2
1 b 1
2 c 4
3 d 9
```

Expect output

```
  A B C
0 a 2 4/9
1 b 1 4/9
2 c 4 4/9
3 d 9 4/9
```

Kindly remind that: each rows of column(C) are the same. 4 & 9 are selected and splited them with '/' (Should be string of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need join by `/` all values of `B` column greater like `3` by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) use:

```
df['C'] = '/'.join(df.loc[df.B.gt(3), 'B'].astype(str))
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  a  2  4/9
1  b  1  4/9
2  c  4  4/9
3  d  9  4/9
```

Comment: God you so fast and great answer! i am going to try! but can you please explain me about df.B.gt(3)... what gt() is? i dont get it thank you! and how to FIND OUT values small than 3( you know it will need in future)

Comment: @smellinglady - It is [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) ;)